# Argument changes to something else in .bat Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I made an Installation script for my Company that automatically cleans and Updates new computers we get.

One of these things is Removing the Office C2R's that come preinstalled in all different Languages.

I used the offscrubc2r.vbs script that is available on GitHub, and it worked great, but it unfortunately stopped working in the recent Windows 11 Versions, so I searched for an alterative.

I found the SaRa command line script that you can download here: https://aka.ms/SaRAEnterpriseHelper

And when I put that Command into the .bat file and run it, I have the Following Problem:

Original Command:

`%temp%\installscript\SaRa_cmd\SaRAcmd.exe -S OfficeScrubScenario –AcceptEula -Officeversion All`

The command that shows up in the CMD window:

`Temp\installscript\SaRa_cmd\SaRAcmd.exe -S OfficeScrubScenario ÔÇôAcceptEula -Officeversion All`

The Error I get:

```
Starting Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant Command Line (17.00.9663.009).
```

```
01: Unidentified Argument Found Scenario finished with exit code: [1].
```

```
SaRA Command Line is closing, Please wait...
```

So, as you can see, the argument gets changed to `ÔÇôAcceptEula` instead of `-AcceptEula`

If you open cmd and run the command manually, it works flawlessly, this only happens when running in a .bat file.

I tried rearranging the arguments. But that didn't help

I have no clue what could be causing this

Please tell me what the Problem is

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I'd suspect that your batch has been saved in some Unicode format, not in ANSI. Make sure that it's in ANSI.

Comment: Thx for the Idea, but the argument changes to ûAcceptEula in ANSI. It was in UTF-8

Comment: Delete the `-` in `-AcceptEula` and type it again. It's some other character that only looks like a dash.

Comment: Yes, i also saw it 1,5h ago, i think it's a Minus. That fixed the Problem. I guess CMD converts the Minus to a Dash. I only copied it from a Website, and it works Flawlessly when copying into CMD.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was the Character before AcceptEula, it was a Minus or something. And it works when copying into CMD because it Probably converts that to a dash.